# Duplicate Values Being Inserted on explode() created Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, curl, domdocument

Here is my script and the logic behind it

```
////There's some more stuff right here but it's not really relevant. Right now 
////Because I'm doing tests i'm doing I'm limiting it to 3 posts in `$my_query`

//create empty arrays before loop to initialize array
$array = array();

//start loop (each contains a my way of getting a new url)
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

//misc stuff to get the URL, SKU and ID
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
$title = $product->get_title();
$sku = $product->get_sku();
$sku_id = $sku . '_' . $post_id;
$urltitle = urlencode($title);

//assign url
$url = 'http://www.example.com/search?=' . $urltitle;

//Using CURL to get HTML from $url
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, surl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();

@$dom->loadHTML($html);

//retreive links from loaded html
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {

//search nodeValue's for something specific in string
if (strpos($link->nodeValue, 'Over $') !== false) {

    //nodeValue found. Start counter and make $f not empty
    $f = 1;
                                                  }
        //$f is now not empty
        if (!empty($f)) {

                //Starting at nodeValue's immediately after 'Over $'
                if ($f > 1) {

                        //Put nodeValue's in $array along with corresponding $sku and $id
                        $array[] .= $link->nodeValue . '|' . $sku_id;

                            }
//increment $f by +1 once $f is not empty
$f++;
}

//we only want the first 4 values after the searched text was found ($f = 2, 3, 4 and 5)
if ($f == 6) {
                        break;
}

//end foreach loop         
}

//make $f empty again so it remains false at beginning of while loop (don't completely understand this but I was having issues without it)
$f = NULL;

//end loop. Start again.
endwhile;
```

After the loops the array stores the values I've obtained and outputs fine.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts|SKU1_9545
    [1] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts|SKU1_9545
    [2] => CarParts.com|SKU1_9545
    [3] => Auto Parts Train|SKU1_9545
    [4] => Automotive Rims & Wheels|SKU2_8564
    [5] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts|SKU2_8564
    [6] => Under 16 inch|SKU2_8564
    [7] => 16 – 18 inch|SKU2_8564
    [8] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts|SKU3_7589
    [9] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts|SKU3_7589
    [10] => McGard|SKU3_7589
    [11] => Rugged Ridge|SKU3_7589
)
```

Because I have duplicate Keys and Values on both sides, I'm needing to make this into a multidimensional array with $sku_id as the parent arrays.

Here's what I mustered up:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $level):
        $explode = explode('|', $level);
       foreach ($itemprods as $k =>$attribute):
           $explode = explode('|', $attribute);
             $variables[$explode[1]][] = $explode[0];
       endforeach;
endforeach;
```

This seems to work slightly, as the output of `$variables` is

```
Array
(
    [SKU1_9545] => Array
        (
            [0] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [1] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [2] => CarParts.com
            [3] => Auto Parts Train
            [4] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [5] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [6] => CarParts.com
            [7] => Auto Parts Train
            [8] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [9] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [10] => CarParts.com
            [11] => Auto Parts Train
            [12] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [13] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [14] => CarParts.com
            [15] => Auto Parts Train
            [16] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [17] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [18] => CarParts.com
            [19] => Auto Parts Train
            [20] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [21] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [22] => CarParts.com
            [23] => Auto Parts Train
            [24] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [25] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [26] => CarParts.com
            [27] => Auto Parts Train
            [28] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [29] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [30] => CarParts.com
            [31] => Auto Parts Train
            [32] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [33] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [34] => CarParts.com
            [35] => Auto Parts Train
            [36] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [37] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [38] => CarParts.com
            [39] => Auto Parts Train
            [40] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [41] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [42] => CarParts.com
            [43] => Auto Parts Train
            [44] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [45] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [46] => CarParts.com
            [47] => Auto Parts Train
        )

    [SKU2_8564] => Array
        (
            [0] => Automotive Rims & Wheels
            [1] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [2] => Under 16 inch
            [3] => 16 – 18 inch
            [4] => Automotive Rims & Wheels
            [5] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [6] => Under 16 inch
            [7] => 16 – 18 inch
            [8] => Automotive Rims & Wheels
            [9] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [10] => Under 16 inch
            [11] => 16 – 18 inch
            [12] => Automotive Rims & Wheels
            [13] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [14] => Under 16 inch
            [15] => 16 – 18 inch
            [16] => Automotive Rims & Wheels
            [17] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [18] => Under 16 inch
            [19] => 16 – 18 inch
            [20] => Automotive Rims & Wheels
            [21] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [22] => Under 16 inch
            [23] => 16 – 18 inch
            [24] => Automotive Rims & Wheels
            [25] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [26] => Under 16 inch
            [27] => 16 – 18 inch
            [28] => Automotive Rims & Wheels
            [29] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [30] => Under 16 inch
            [31] => 16 – 18 inch
            [32] => Automotive Rims & Wheels
            [33] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [34] => Under 16 inch
            [35] => 16 – 18 inch
            [36] => Automotive Rims & Wheels
            [37] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [38] => Under 16 inch
            [39] => 16 – 18 inch
            [40] => Automotive Rims & Wheels
            [41] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [42] => Under 16 inch
            [43] => 16 – 18 inch
            [44] => Automotive Rims & Wheels
            [45] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [46] => Under 16 inch
            [47] => 16 – 18 inch
        )

    [SKU3_7589] => Array
        (
            [0] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [1] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [2] => McGard
            [3] => Rugged Ridge
            [4] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [5] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [6] => McGard
            [7] => Rugged Ridge
            [8] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [9] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [10] => McGard
            [11] => Rugged Ridge
            [12] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [13] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [14] => McGard
            [15] => Rugged Ridge
            [16] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [17] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [18] => McGard
            [19] => Rugged Ridge
            [20] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [21] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [22] => McGard
            [23] => Rugged Ridge
            [24] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [25] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [26] => McGard
            [27] => Rugged Ridge
            [28] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [29] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [30] => McGard
            [31] => Rugged Ridge
            [32] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [33] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [34] => McGard
            [35] => Rugged Ridge
            [36] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [37] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [38] => McGard
            [39] => Rugged Ridge
            [40] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [41] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [42] => McGard
            [43] => Rugged Ridge
            [44] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [45] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [46] => McGard
            [47] => Rugged Ridge
        )

)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?
All the values in the multi-dimensional array are correct, I just need to figure out a way to remove the duplicate values in each dimension.

The end result I'm looking to achieve will look like this

```
Array
(
    [SKU1_9545] => Array
        (
            [0] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [1] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [2] => CarParts.com
            [3] => Auto Parts Train
        )

    [SKU2_8564] => Array
        (
            [0] => Automotive Rims & Wheels
            [1] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [2] => Under 16 inch
            [3] => 16 – 18 inch
        )

    [SKU3_7589] => Array
        (
            [0] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
            [1] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
            [2] => McGard
            [3] => Rugged Ridge
        )

)
```

Comment: You could use `array_unique` on them or you can do `array_search` before adding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this bit:

```
foreach ($itemprods as $k =>$attribute):
    $explode = explode('|', $attribute);
    $variables[$explode[1]][] = $explode[0];
```

Add a check in

```
foreach ($itemprods as $k =>$attribute):
    $explode = explode('|', $attribute);
    if( !isset($variables[$explode[1]]) || array_search($explode[0], $variables[$explode[1]]) === false)
         $variables[$explode[1]][] = $explode[0];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

> array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful

Please note the `=== false` this means (extra `=`) to also check the type.  This is necessary because `array_search` returns the index which can be `0` and `0` is also `false` but it's not "boolean" `false`.  So this prevents adding the item, if the search says it's the first element in the array, ie index 0.

In the documentation this warning is given:

> **Warning** This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

**Alternatively** you could run `array_unique` but this would require a loop after compiling the multidimensional array.

```
  foreach( $variables as &$array){
     $array = array_unique($array);
  }
```

The `&` in `as &$array` is pass by reference, so we can update the array without creating a new array.

**One last way** is to abuse the fact that keys are unique and create the nested array with a key that matches it's value:

```
foreach ($itemprods as $k =>$attribute):
    $explode = explode('|', $attribute);
    if(!isset($variables[$explode[1]]) || !isset($variables[$explode[1]][$explode[0]]))
         $variables[$explode[1]][$explode[0]] = $explode[0];
```

This last one would be the fastest, as `isset` does not do a function call.  But  you end up with an array like this:

```
[SKU1_9545] => Array
    (
        [Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
        [Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
        [CarParts.com] => CarParts.com
        [Auto Parts Train] => Auto Parts Train
    )
```

You can use `array_values` to strip the keys out like `array_values($array['SKU1_9545'])` but it sort of defeats the purpose.

**UPDATE**

As you mentioned in the comments, for the 1st and last way I mentioned you should check if the main array isset first.

```
 if( !isset($variables[$explode[1]]) || ... )
```

When PHP sees the first part of an `OR` is true, then it does not evaluate the second part, because the entire condition is true.  So it's important to check that first then the other one.  So we can check with the `OR` because if the main nested array is not set, surely the elements in it cannot be duplicate yet.

Comment: Thank you. Looking into it.  On first try I am getting the error `Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given` many times, assumingly because my second array_search parameter is not initialized yet in the loop

Comment: Yes that would be the issue.  I updated it to check for `!isset($variables[$explode[1]])` first

Comment: Got it with `if( !isset($variables[$explode[1]]) || array_search($explode[0], $variables[$explode[1]]) === false):`
 `$variables[$explode[1]][] = $explode[0];`
`endif;`! Was having issues with trying the other methods but I'm sure if I played around with them I could get them to work. Thanks again!

Comment: Yep, the last way I mentioned is the fastest of them all, but you wind up with string keys, which may or may not be desirable.  But `isset` is much faster then `array_search`, this is because "technically" `isset` is not a function, but a language construct.

Comment: Yes the last way removes the duplicates and puts the Key and Value as the same string. `[Under 16 inch] => Under 16 inch` whereas the first one puts it in an indexed array `[2] => Under 16 inch`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need two loops in that second part. This worked for me:

```
$variables=[];
foreach ($myArray as $row){
     $explode = explode('|', $row);
     if (!in_array($explode[1],array_keys($variables))){
         $variables[$explode[1]]=[];
     }
     $variables[$explode[1]][] = $explode[0];
}
```

Comment: I forgot about `in_array` lol.  I don't use it much.  Typically I use the value as a key, if I need them to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the input array:

```
$array = Array(
                "0" => "Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts|SKU1_9545",
                "1" => "Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts|SKU1_9545",
                "2" => "CarParts.com|SKU1_9545",
                "3" => "Auto Parts Train|SKU1_9545",
                "4" => "Automotive Rims & Wheels|SKU2_8564",
                "5" => "Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts|SKU2_8564",
                "6" => "Under 16 inch|SKU2_8564",
                "7" => "16 – 18 inch|SKU2_8564",
                "8" => "Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts|WS49X4_9874",
                "9" => "Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts|WS49X4_9874",
                "10" => "McGard|WS49X4_9874",
                "11" => "Rugged Ridge|WS49X4_9874"
               );
```

You can then use a `result array` and the `array_key_exists()` like this:

```
$results = array();     // array to keep results

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    $explode = explode('|', $value);             // exlpode the value

    if(!array_key_exists($explode[1], $results)) // check if key already exists in results
    {
        $results[$explode[1]] = array();       // if not make a new key
    }

    array_push($results[$explode[1]], $explode[0]);  // push a value to the key
}

print_r($results);
```

will output:

```
Array ( 
        [SKU1_9545] => Array ( [0] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts 
                               [1] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts 
                               [2] => CarParts.com 
                               [3] => Auto Parts Train
                             )
        [SKU2_8564] => Array ( [0] => Automotive Rims & Wheels
                               [1] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
                               [2] => Under 16 inch [3] => 16 – 18 inch
                             )
        [WS49X4_9874] => Array([0] => Motor Vehicle Wheel Parts
                               [1] => Motor Vehicle Suspension Parts
                               [2] => McGard
                               [3] => Rugged Ridge
                              )
      )
```